# Low pass filter not working in MathNet.Filter, F#

Tags: f#, math.net, mathnet-filtering

I am trying to use a low-pass filter with F# using MathNet.Filter and when I plot the results is not working.
I have found some similar questions in C#, but when I reproduce the code in F# The result is wrong.

Here it is the way I am using MathNet.Filter:

```
let fs ,fcut, order = 5000., 2.5, 5  // set the filter parameters
let lowPass2 = MathNet.Filtering.OnlineFilter.CreateLowpass(MathNet.Filtering.ImpulseResponse.Finite,fs,fcut,order)
let disp_beam_f = disp_beam |> lowPass2.ProcessSamples // apply the filter

// I print max/min to do a quick check
(disp_beam_f |> Array.min, disp_beam |> Array.min )
```

Then, when I plot some data my result is:
[image: Comparative between the filtered and the unfiltered file]
When I plot just the filtered data, the plot looks like the original data, but with a different scale:
[image: plot where only the filtered data is shown]
I have already tried changing the order of the filter, and not using the order of the filter, the result is better, but it is not the filtered data.

- What I am doing wrong?  I understand that **fs** is the frequency sampling (in Hz), **fcut** the frequency at which high frequencies are cut (in Hz) and **order** represents how much (or fast) the signal for frequencies above fcut are attenuated.

For more information, here there is a script:
https://gist.github.com/josesoyo/f45b59a035c3e2ec2cdf0fe1f95cc84b
and a sample of data is in : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rA4B21i-S5g2wrB4eK7xk3_A6Rs0tLHf
The result should be this file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ukmWtzFm_I4ou3zuQcLWCrFIOJs2eV41

---

Edit Based on [**Gene Belitski** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888244/low-pass-filter-not-working-in-mathnet-filter-f/48897125#48897125) which I believes clarifies the case:

Running the next script shows better what is the problem I have:

```
#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
#r @"..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.3.8.0\lib\net40\MathNet.Numerics.dll"
#r @"..\packages\MathNet.Filtering.0.4.0\lib\net40\MathNet.Filtering.dll"
#load @"..\packages\FSharp.Charting.0.91.1\lib\net45\FSharp.Charting.fsx"

let length, samplingRate,  amplitude = 750, 44100.,20.
let flow, fhigh = 200., 15000.
let lo = Generate.Sinusoidal(length,samplingRate,flow,amplitude)
let hi = Generate.Sinusoidal(length,samplingRate,fhigh,amplitude/4.)
let sumLoHi = lo |> Array.map2 (+) hi
let fs ,fcut, order = float(samplingRate), 5000., 10 

// first low pass filter
let lowPass2 = MathNet.Filtering.OnlineFilter.CreateLowpass(MathNet.Filtering.ImpulseResponse.Finite,fs,fcut,order)
let filtered = sumLoHi |> lowPass2.ProcessSamples

// second low pass filter
let lowPass3 = MathNet.Filtering.OnlineFilter.CreateLowpass(MathNet.Filtering.ImpulseResponse.Finite,fs,fcut/5.,order)
let filtered_2 = sumLoHi |> lowPass3.ProcessSamples

// plot
Chart.Combine([Chart.Line(lo, Name="lo", Color=Color.DarkBlue);
               Chart.Line(sumLoHi, Name="sumLoHi", Color=Color.LightSkyBlue);
               Chart.Line(filtered, Name="filtered ratio fcut/SamplingRatio = 0.1", Color=Color.Purple);
               Chart.Line(filtered_2, Name="filtered ratio fcut/SamplingRatio = 0.02", Color=Color.Fuchsia)])
|> Chart.WithLegend(Title="Combined",Docking=ChartTypes.Docking.Bottom)
|> Chart.WithTitle("OnlineFilter")
```

And the result is:
[image]

I have specified the ratio between the samplingRate and the filtering frequency because I believe that the problem problem is related with this parameter. Is it that I shouldn't use OnlineFilter in this way or is it something else?

I have also tried to use IIR and FIR filters and the result is the same. Instead, a similar situation with python/scipy works well.

Comment: Can you make your example self-contained by including some sample values for `disp_beam`?

Comment: Sure, is the last update ok? For the plots I used python, if you want a small script I can do it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your sample data it is hard to determine if the observed behavior is right or wrong. It might help putting together a quick sample where it would be obvious if the filter works or not; then review your code.

For example, we may take a wave data of a lower frequency, add to it another wave of higher frequency, then apply the filter to the sum filtering out higher frequency  and expect that the filtered data will resemble the lower wave.

The below script implements the above scenario:

```
#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
#r @"..\packages\MathNet.Numerics.3.8.0\lib\net40\MathNet.Numerics.dll"
#r @"..\packages\MathNet.Filtering.0.4.0\lib\net40\MathNet.Filtering.dll"
#load @"..\packages\FSharp.Charting.0.91.1\lib\net45\FSharp.Charting.fsx"

open FSharp.Charting
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Filtering
open System.Drawing

let length, samplingRate,  amplitude = 250, 44100.,20.
let lo = Generate.Sinusoidal(length,samplingRate,1000.,amplitude)
let hi = Generate.Sinusoidal(length,samplingRate,15000.,amplitude/3.)
let sumLoHi = lo |> Array.map2 (+) hi
let fs ,fcut, order = 44100., 5000., 10
let lowPass2 = MathNet.Filtering.OnlineFilter.CreateLowpass(MathNet.Filtering.ImpulseResponse.Finite,fs,fcut,order)
let filtered = sumLoHi |> lowPass2.ProcessSamples
Chart.Combine([Chart.Line(lo, Name="lo", Color=Color.DarkBlue);
               Chart.Line(sumLoHi, Name="sumLoHi", Color=Color.LightSkyBlue);
               Chart.Line(filtered, Name="filtered", Color=Color.Purple)])
|> Chart.WithLegend(Title="Combined",Docking=ChartTypes.Docking.Bottom)
```

Two `sine` waves of the same sampling rate and data lengths and frequencies 1kHz for `lo` and 15kHz for `hi` are combined into `sumLoHi`. Then the filter is applied to the latter cutting off frequencies above 5kHz getting `filtered` data. The resulting combined chart of `lo`, `sumLoHi` and `filtered` shows that the filter is working just fine:

[image: combined chart]

Comment: Thank you, with this case it is easy to explain my problem. If you modify the next lines, a similar behaviour to mine appears: 

**let length, samplingRate,  amplitude = 1500, 500.,20.**
**let fs ,fcut, order = float(samplingRate), 10., 10**

And finally **low** is changed to  **1** and **fhigh **to **50**
.
In this case, the amplitude of the filtered signal is reduced to half the amplitude of the original signal. I see this happens because fcut/samplingRate is very small. I don't see this behaviour using python/scipy

Comment: here it is the equivalent code on python https://gist.github.com/josesoyo/24cb9a8c87ec53e6f443be1de8d9f027

Comment: I have done an edition based in your answer I hope that it will help to understand my problem

Comment: @JoseMGonzalez Assuming `scipy` a reference implementation compared to `Mathnet` I'd bring the matter of difference from Python to the attention of Mathnet maintainers as an [issue](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-filtering/issues).

Comment: @JoseMGonzalez Also it looks like that the relevant [issue](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-filtering/issues/8) already has been submitted.

Comment: After applying the suggested change in the code looks like it works!  Thank you very much